# Installing Web application IIS

Tags: wix

Hi I am trying to install a web application using WIX. I am not sure if what I have is correct but I am getting this error in my log files:

My wxs file:

```
    <ComponentGroup Id='IISConfig'>

<Component Id='WebAppPool' Guid='5EC0510D-BE49-4FE9-9572-5695DB9BD343' Directory='INSTALLLOCATION'>
  <CreateFolder/>
  <iis:WebAppPool Id="WebAppPool" Name="DefaultAppPool" />

  <iis:WebSite Id='DefaultWebSite' Description='Default Web Site' Directory='INSTALLLOCATION' WebApplication='WebApplication'>
    <iis:WebAddress Id='AllUnassigned' Port='80' />
    <iis:WebDirProperties Id='WebDirProperties' Execute='yes'/>
  </iis:WebSite>
</Component>


<Component Id='WebVirtualDirComponent' Guid='52D0B071-0801-4B93-8C8F-F5FC92DD8D8F' Directory='INSTALLLOCATION'>
  <CreateFolder/>
  <iis:WebVirtualDir Id='WebVirtualDir' Alias='[PRODUCTNAME]' Directory='INSTALLLOCATION' WebSite='DefaultWebSite'>
    <iis:WebDirProperties Id='WebVirtualDirProperties' Execute='yes' WindowsAuthentication='yes'/>
    <iis:WebApplication Id='WebApplication' Name='[PRODUCTNAME]' WebAppPool='WebAppPool'>
      <iis:WebApplicationExtension Extension='dll' Executable='[#mod_Gsoap.dll]' CheckPath='yes' Script='yes'/>
    </iis:WebApplication>
  </iis:WebVirtualDir>
</Component>


</ComponentGroup>
```

Any my log file:

```
MSI (s) (90:C4) [14:48:38:200]: Executing op: CustomActionSchedule(Action=WriteIIS7ConfigChanges,ActionType=11265,Source=BinaryData,Target=**********,CustomActionData=**********)
MSI (s) (90:AC) [14:48:38:216]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Windows\Installer\MSIAB38.tmp, Entrypoint: WriteIIS7ConfigChanges
WriteIIS7ConfigChanges:  Error 0x80040154: Failed to open AppHostWritableAdminManager to configure IIS7
WriteIIS7ConfigChanges:  Error 0x80040154: WriteIIS7ConfigChanges Failed.
CustomAction WriteIIS7ConfigChanges returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 14:48:38: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
```

I would be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message means the IIS7 COM object for writing to the IIS configuration is not properly registered on the machine. Not sure the best way to fix the issue, but you might try repairing (or uninstall/install) IIS.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, IIS was not installed at all. D'oh.